# Google Apps Script URLFetchApp parse result in log but not in cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an app script I am using to try to and check the tracking number status.

```
function TrackingNumberDetail(varTrackingNumber) {

  var options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'method' : 'get',
    'headers' : {"API-KEY": "123456789", "API-SECRET": "987654321"},
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.buyformeretail.com/api/tracking/status?tracking_number=' + varTrackingNumber, options);
  
  var content = response.getContentText();

  return content
  
}
```

I am able to use it to get the value of a tracking number in a sheet (say in cell A1) by using `TrackingNumberDetail(A1)` in B1 and then the output is `{"success":true,"status":200,"message":"Tracking Number Information","data":{"tracking_number":"632874061409","status":"Pending"}}` but I am trying to parse the results using `return content.data.status;` and I am having issues.

If I set the tracking number in the script instead of using varTrackingNumber and force the output to the log using Logger.log I get the parsed content output with just Pending but when the variable is used and I try to return it to a cell I get that issue (really only when returning it to the cell).

I saw [this q&a here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70089174/google-apps-script-returns-desired-result-in-execution-log-but-cell-in-spreadsh) but that did not help when I tried to modify it.

Answer (score 3):

`getContentText()` returns a string value. So, in your script, `{"success":true,"status":200,"message":"Tracking Number Information","data":{"tracking_number":"632874061409","status":"Pending"}}` is a string. I thought that the reason for your current issue might be due to that `content` is not parsed as a JSON object. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var content = response.getContentText();

return content
```

#### To:

```
var content = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
return content.data.status;
```

- By this, if `response.getContentText()` is `{"success":true,"status":200,"message":"Tracking Number Information","data":{"tracking_number":"632874061409","status":"Pending"}}`, `Pending` is returned.

#### References:

- [getContentText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response)
- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)